# Commerce store website Items are not visible in the content tree

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have successfully installed Sitecore Experience Commerce 9 on my Windows 10 machine. Everything is working fine but I didn't see store website which is coming out of the box from Sitecore Commerce Installation.

However, I can see Commerce related items under the Sitecore node and all other application are just working fine i.e. bizfx, identity, minions etc.

Update 1: `/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts` content item is there.

[image]

But i didn't find  `/sitecore/content/Sitecore` item.

[image]

Also, i didn't see Storefront application in SXA Site Manager.
[image]

**Environment**:

Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (WDP XP0 packages)

Sitecore.Commerce.2018.03-2.1.55

Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.7 rev. 180410 for 9.0

Comment: Which installation guide / blog posts have you followed? Your problem is that you cannot navigate to sxa.storefront.com? Is that correct?

Comment: I am following https://buoctrenmay.com/2018/03/09/step-by-step-guide-for-sitecore-commerce-9-installation-on-your-machine/ guide The issue is, i don't find any items related to Storefront under sitecore node in the content tree.

Comment: Can you update question with screenshot how your content tree looks like especially under these paths /sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts and /sitecore/content/Sitecore. I believe that /sitecore/content/Sitecore is empty. If you navigate to SXA Site manager, do you see Storefront website before "website"? https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/getting_started_with_sxa/tenants_and_sites/manage_multiple_sites_with_the_sxa_site_manager

Comment: Which version of Sitecore, Sitecore Commerce and SXA have you precisely installed?

Comment: @PeterProchazka, Thanks for your input. I have added environment details in the question.

Comment: I don't see any "website" site definition and only helixbase. I am afraid that helixbase somehow spoiled your installation. When did you deployed helixbase solution? Before installing Commerce Server?

Comment: Could be that the Helixbase is somehow not compatible with SXA (maybe they are overriding same pipelines or something like) and that is causing you trouble with installing Storefront and using SXA overall.

Comment: Yes. Even i am also thinking the same. Somehow Helixbase creating a problem here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79137/discussion-between-peter-prochazka-and-arvind-gehlot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with SXA version 1.7 that you have used. Based on requirements from Sitecore it should be 1.6 for Sitecore Commerce 9.

Please install SXA 1.6 instead and "Replace all" when asked.

I would also recommend you to use SQL Server 2016 SP1 instead of SQL Server 2017 as your installation might not be supported by Sitecore Support folks.

See more information about compatibility here:
- https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/804595

Comment: I had the same issue and used SXA 1.7 instead of SXA 1.6. You shouldn't reinstall everything from scratch. Just download and install SXA 1.6 package and choose Replace All. Works for me

Comment: Thanks Andrei for pointing this out. I have updated answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the script
   `/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/CXA - Internal/Web API/CreateDefaultStorefrontTenantAndSite`
2. Add the following snippet before Function `CreateCXATenant`.

> ```
> Function Write-Progress {
>         [CmdletBinding()]
>         param(
>         [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
>         $Activity,
>         [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
>         $CurrentOperation,
>         [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
>         $Status,
>         [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
>         $PercentComplete,
>         [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
>         [switch]$Completed)
>         process {
>         # do nothing
>          }
>  }
> ```

3. Save your change and run the script in Sitecore Powershell will resolve the issue.

Please follow the below link for detailed information:

http://andrewsutherland.azurewebsites.net/2019/05/01/installing-sitecore-experience-commerce-9-1-with-default-storefront-tenant-and-site/